# Probability problem - binomial distibution

Tags: probability

Please help me out, I need to solve this problem, unfortunately I don't have any good way to approach this task

*The keeper of a certain king’s treasure receives the task of filling each of 100 urns
with 100 gold coins. While fulfilling this task, he substitutes one lead coin for one
gold coin in each urn. The king suspects deceit on the part of the sentry and has
two methods at his disposal of auditing the contents of the urns. The first method
consists of randomly choosing one coin from each of the 100 urns. The second
method consists of randomly choosing four coins from each one of 25 of the 100
urns. Which method provides the largest probability of uncovering the deceit?*

The answers is "the second method" was solved by binomial distribution. The probabilities are 0.634 and 0.640 accordingly to the textbook "Understanding Probability"

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: make it more formal: assign some names to events that can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: call $p_1$ the probability that a given urn reveals the deceit when one draws one coin from it and $p_4$ when one draws four coins. Your first step would be to compute $p_1$ and $p_4$. The text of the exercise probably means that the urn reveals the deceit if and only if the lead coin is the coin drawn, respectively is among the four coins drawn. Then $p_1$ and $p_4$ are very simple functions of $n$ the number of coins in each urn. Your second step would be to write the global probabilities $P_1$ and $P_4$ of uncovering the deceit as functions of $p_1$ and $p_4$ respectively. Sub-hint: consider the probabilities of *not* uncovering the deceit.

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually necessary to calculate the numbers to reach the conclusion, though you may need to satisfy your teacher.

The expected number of lead coins found is $\frac{1}{100}$ times the number of coins inspected.

If you only looked at four coins, either drawn from four different urns or from the same urn, then you would be more likely to find two or more lead coins in the first case, and so also more likely to find zero lead coins in the first case (you might work out these probabilities of finding zero).  So the probability of finding no lead coins when repeating these 25 times is higher in the first case (again you can work this out). So in the original problem the probability of finding at least one lead coin is higher in the second case (easily calculated from the previous numbers).

Comment: Is the fact that it is more likely to find zero lead coins in the first case, a consequence of the fact that it is more likely to find two or more lead coins in the first case?

Comment: @Didier Piau: Yes, since it is impossible to find two or more lead coins in the second case when looking at four coins from a single urn, and the expected number of lead coins found is the same in both cases.

Comment: Right, since $E(X)\ge1-P(X=0)$ for every nonnegative integer valued $X$, with an equality if and only if $X=0$ or $1$ with full probability. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help

regarding Didier Piau hint

$$p1=\frac{99}{100} $$ - uncovering deceit by the first method ,so

$$P1 = ( \frac{99}{100} ) ^ {100} $$

probability of uncovering the deceit for the second method might be looking like that

$$p2 = ( 1 - \binom{100}{4} ( \frac{1}{100} ) ^ 4  ( \frac {99}{100} ) ^ {96} ) $$

and

$$P2 = p2 ^ {100} $$

I am not sure if this's right , but at least it makes sense  for me :)

Comment: Sorry but you are off the mark: the first step, using $n=100$, should give you $p_1=1/n$ and $p_4=4/n$. Let me suggest that now, either you signal that you understand why these formulas hold, or you explain what is unclear to you in them. Then, we shall proceed to the next step.

Comment: I understand the way you are thinking and I just can't figure out how are you going to proceed the solution with your p1 and p4. Please show the continue at least with p1. Thanks!

Comment: First step: do you see why $p_1$ is $1/n$ and not $(n-1)/n$ and can you explain the reason, in formulas or in words?

Comment: Of course _p1=1/n_ - probability of covering the deceit for one urn. I used _p1=(n-1)/n_ as probability of uncovering the deceit for one urn ,so the probability of uncovering for all runs will be _P1=(99/100)^(100)_

Comment: Right, $p_1$ is $1/n$. But forget this value for a moment and just call it $p_1$. Next question is: What could be $P_1$ as a function of $p_1$ and $n$? That is, you have $n$ trials, each with a probability $p_1$ of success, and you want the probability $P_1$ that at least one of these $n$ is successful (maybe one of them, maybe more, but not zero). Hint: $P_1$ is **not** $(1-p_1)^n$...

Comment: ok, may be $P_{1}(X=k) =  \binom{n}{k} (p_{1})^{k}(1-p_{1})^{n-k}$, where X-number of success

Comment: Sorry, but *maybe* is not an acceptable answer... Forget your binomial, it is much too complicated for me. Let us try again: What is the probability that **none** of these $n$ trials is successful?

Comment: $(p_{1})^n$ - all of them are successful, so $1-(p_{1})^n$ - none of them are successful. Right?

Comment: No, not right: $1-(p_1)^n$ is the probability that **at least one** is not successful. You want the probability that **all of them** fail. So...

Comment: I don't know. I already wrote the answer for **all of them are fail**. If $p_{1}$ probability of success, so $1-p_{1}$ is probability of fail, so $(1-p_{1})^{n}$ probability all of them are fail

Comment: Yessir! Next: if all of them fail with probability $(1-p_1)^n$, the probability $P_1$ that at least one of them is successful is $P_1=1-(1-p_1)^n$, right? So we have $P_1$. If this is OK, let us turn to $P_4$. Obviously there are $n/4$ trials instead of $n$ and one needs the probability $p_4$ that a single given elementary trial is successful. Your next (and almost final) steps are (1) to describe the trial whose $p_4$ is the probability of sucess, (2) to write $p_4$ as a function of $n$, and (3) to write $P_4$ as a function of $p_4$ and $n$.

Comment: ok, obviously $p_{4}=\frac{4}{100}$ - probability of success, all trials are fail $(1-p_{4})^{25}$ and using your pattern $P_{4}=1-(1-p_{4})^{25}$ and now it's finally done. I don't know why I was trying to solve this by binomial dist, the solution was much easier. Thanks!

Comment: Didier, one of the my mistakes was that I used binomial dist do you know how can I distinguish simple probability problem from probability problem solved by binomial distribution

Comment: Why is $p_4$ equal to $4/100$? // Your step $p_4\to P_4$ is correct. // Did you check the numerical values provided in your textbook? // Your last question should probably be rephrased as "Which distributions for which situations?", and to that I know no simple answer, except the ususl one: THINK. // One comment: now that you got the solution and that you got it yourself, you definitely should write it as completely as possible and post it here, and finally... congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

I am solving the same question and puzzled by the choosing four coins from each of the 25 urns as well.
However, I think I solved this problem and I would like to shed some light to this problem to people who are puzzled by this problem like I were.
First, we need to solve for the probability for not finding the lead coin for 4 draws out of 100 coins at each of the 25 urn. The solution should be 99/100*98/99*97/98*96/97=96/100.
So we have the probability for not finding the lead coin for each of the 25 independent trial.
Second, we apply binomial formula.
The probability of finding at least 1 lead coin out of 25 independent trial of the 25 urn is 1-(96/100)^25=0.6396 which is very close to the 0.640 indicated by the solution of the book.
Hope this helps.